# Is it possible to check if a User is Locked Out?

Tags: salesforce

Using the Salesforce Web Services API is it possible to check (or query) if a User is Locked Out (if they have attempted to log in unsuccessfully too many times and are therefore blocked from logging in)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there is no specific field on the User object to indicate that they are locked out, you can query the `LoginHistory` object.

```
select Id, UserId, LoginTime, Status from LoginHistory where
    UserId = 'xxxxxxxxx' order by LoginTime desc limit 20
```

Then loop through the results, checking the value of the `Status` field. If the user has been locked out, the most recent login attempts will have a value of "Password Lockout" in this field.

Other possible values of this `Status` field include:

- Success
- User is Inactive
- Invalid Password
- Failed: API security token required
- Failed: Computer activation pending
- Failed: Computer activation required
- Failed: Invalid Timestamp
- Failed: Mobile License Required

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind; I found the answer.

It says in the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm):

> The password **lockout status** and the **ability to reset the User locked-out status** is not available via the API. You must check and reset the User password lockout status using the user interface.

Answer (score 0):

For admin users - it's now possible to unlock users on iphone / ipad via the SalesforceA mobile app. https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/salesforcea/id731117958?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

In Apex, I can check the IsPasswordLocked field on UserLogin object to check  if a User is locked out or not by using the following SOQL -:

[SELECT IsPasswordLocked FROM UserLogin 
 WHERE UserId = 'ENTER YOUR USER ID HERE'];